# C# - Using reflection with JsonSchema4.FromTypeAsync

Tags: c#, reflection, jsonschema

**[INTRO]**
I know there are about a zillion QA about generics and reflections everywhere, but it's becoming a blackhole to me, and I'm only getting more lost the more I read!!

What i need to do is simple, and I'm amazed that it hasn't been addressed before.

**[SAMPLE]** Consider the following snippit:

```
public async Task<string> generateJsonSchema(string model)
{
    try
    {
        string modelName = "Models." + model;
        Type t = Type.GetType(modelName, false);
        JsonSchema4 schema = await JsonSchema4.FromTypeAsync<t>();
        return schema.ToJson();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.WriteToLogFile(ex.ToString(), "exception");
        return "";
    }
}
```

**[PROBLEM]** Now the main problem is that variable ***t*** is evaluated at **runtime**, thus, `JsonSchema4.FromTypeAsync<t>()` throws the error `'t' is a variable but is used like a type` when trying to build **compile time**

Whoever used *JsonSchema4* will understand what I'm trying to achieve here.
Instead of creating a generate function for each of my models, or make a switch/if-else logic,

**[QUESTION]**
How to make it receive the model name as a **string parameter**, and convert the string-model-name to model-type and pass it to jSonSchema4 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, as you say, `t` is evaluated as runtime.

I also ran into this Problem and solved it by creating a `MethodInfo` of the method I wanted to invoke, in your case `JsonSchema4.FromTypeAsync<t>()`.

So basically this is want may fix the problem:

```
    var methodInfo = typeof(JsonSchema4).GetMethod("FromTypeAsync", new Type[] { }); //Get the "normal method info", the overload without parameters
    var methodInfoWithType = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(t); //now you have a method with your desired parameter t as TypeParameter
    Task<JsonSchema4> task = methodInfoWithType.Invoke(null, null) as Task<JsonSchema4>; //now you can cast the result from invoke as Task to keep the Async-Await functionality
    var schema = await task;
    return schema.ToJson();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `FromTypeAsync` has multiple overloads, your snippit gives me a `mismatch error`

Comment: You have to change the firsst line to `var methodInfo = typeof(JsonSchema4).GetMethod("FromTypeAsync", new Type[] { });` to get the `FromTypeAsync` without any parameters, then it shouldn't throw the `Exception` which is caused by multiple matches. I'll edit the answer to match.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot.
Please edit your answer with your comment to mark it as correct answer

Comment: The snippet in the answer is now edited an will work :)

Comment: Do you have any experience with NJsonSchema itself? how to force type: "string" instead of the stupid type: ["null", "string"]

Comment: Yes, I have worked with NJSONSchema some time ago. Because `string` is nullable in C# and the `string` type in JSON-Schema isn't, type is set to `["null", "string"]`, the only way to prevent this I know is DataAnnotations like this: `[NJsonSchema.Annotations.NotNull]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }`

Comment: Well, i found a way to fix that with a custom resolver, which leads to another issue, is how to pass `settings` variable in the reflection above :D

Comment: You can get the `MethodInfo` of the overload of `FromTypeAsync<T>(settings)` by changing line one to `var methodInfo = typeof(JsonSchema4).GetMethod("FromTypeAsync", new Type[] { typeof(NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings) });` and then invoke the generic `MethodInfo` with your settings like this: ` `Task<JsonSchema4> task = methodInfoWithType.Invoke(null, new object[] { settings })`